# Intellij - running main class in IDE works but bootRun or bootJar fails for post requests to Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have this java web services Spring Boot application created using gradle in IntelliJ IDE.

If I run the application via right-click on the Main class, all works fine.

However, if i run via gradle -> bootRun or run the bootJar created by building the project I see the following issue:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MY_ACTS_RUN_ENV'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Check your PL/SQL argument, it's problem with data type or number of arguments passed in PL/SQL. Error is `wrong number or types of arguments`

Comment: @pradipforever I guess in that case it should not have run even when running the application via right-click and running the main class.

Comment: No, it will run the application. Since it's the SQL, compiler won't check for the syntax correctness, you will get the exception if there is a syntax error during the runtime.

Comment: I just realized I didn't fully answer the question. The reason `gradle -> bootRun` is throwing error is `gradle` first builds the application, and then run tests. So, these are the exception you are getting from test. Spring boot app has one main test class for Application, and this test is failing.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. Sorry for the late reply, but I was not able to resolve the issue yet :(